# Как проанализировать какие запросы выполняет Hibernate в Spring (IntelliJ IDEA+PostgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Как проанализировать какие будет делаться запросы, когда я буду обращаться к репозитарию Hibernate в Spring? Так же как сравнить производительность запросов?

Я разрабатываю приложение с использованием IntelliJ IDEA,  базу данных использую PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Можно включить логирование SQL, но в Hibernate 5 логи не показывают значения подставляемых параметров LIMIT и OFFSET.

Вместо этого пользуюсь [`p6spy`](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy), подключая его в Spring Boot-приложение с помощью [`p6spy-spring-boot-starter`](https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator).

План выполнения SQL-запроса можно получить с помощью [`EXPLAIN`](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/sql-explain).